# MSAL how to read token's expiry date?

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal, stenciljs

Do you have any idea if there is a way to check if token has expired in Msal (in order to know if should get the acquireTokenSilent or not)
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to check this by yourself. In MSAL, you will call `acquireTokenSilent` method to make a silent request(without prompting the user) to Azure AD to obtain an access token. MSAL will automatically refresh your access token after expiration when calling.

If the silent token acquisition fails for some reasons such as an expired token or password change, you will need to invoke an interactive method to acquire tokens such as acquireTokenPopup or acquireTokenRedirect.

```
var graphScopes = ["user.read", "mail.send"];

   userAgentApplication.loginPopup(graphScopes).then(function (idToken) {
       //Login Success
       userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
           //AcquireTokenSilent Success
       }, function (error) {
           //AcquireTokenSilent Failure, send an interactive request.
           userAgentApplication.acquireTokenPopup(graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
               updateUI();
           }, function (error) {
               console.log(error);
           });
       })
   }, function (error) {
       //login failure
       console.log(error);
   });
```

You can refer to this [article](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js#3-get-an-access-token-to-call-an-api) for more details.

Comment: Sometimes you need to check manually. Because this will also report and renew token, it's working like it was user activity. But sometimes you need to show popup or redirect when token is expired without renewing it.

Comment: MSAL is not loging out users when token is expired and user is inactive.